# Converting specific date/time to timestamp with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am given a spesific task to obtain the current time in a given format, and then convert said time to a Unix timestamp, but I'm feeling a little in over my head here.

After some research and creative googling, I came up with:

```
this.$el.find("#settime").val(moment((new Date).getTime()).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"));
```

Here the:

```
(moment((new Date).getTime()).format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"))
```

...part being the central one.

Now, once the user sees the date in this format, he/she needs to be able to edit it, and feed it back to my application.

At this point, I need it converted.

Assume that a user who's using my application wants 04.08.2015 12:00, but their local time reads 04.08.2015 13:00, so they lower it by an hour and throw it back to my application.

How would I go about converting the updated time back to a timestamp? Note, that the time will always come in at that format (DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the timestamp with the following code

```
Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
```

if you want to convert a datetime string to timestamp, then pass that string to `Date()` and call the `getTime()` method on it and divide the result by 1000.

so if the user provides August 4th 2015 13:13 then

```
Math.floor(new Date("08.04.2015 13:13").getTime() / 1000)
```

will give the timestamp corresponding to the given date `1438674180`,

You will have to convert the modified date into `MM.DD.YYYY` format for this to work.

Refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to know more about Dates